# Can a woman do tayammum in journey?

Tags: wudu, tayammum

A woman can't do wudu in public,so what should she do in journey, is it permissible for her to do tayammum instead of wudu in such a situation?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what kind of a journey this is and why a private cubicle would not be available for Wudu? Almost all modern means of public transport like planes & trains have private spaces and most long distance bus and car services stop at public restrooms with separate enclosure for women. Hence, please elaborate on the circumstances in your question.

Comment: The ruling is tayammum is not valid in presence of water. You should know that even during tayammum a woman may show some of her 'awrah, so there's no differnce in whether she performs wudu' or tayammum.

Comment: Ok,suppose she couldn't find any private space,then what should she do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tayammum is not only valid during the absence of water. If one is ill or during any other instance where the use of water could affect the person negatively it is acceptable to make tayammum. If a woman feels restricted to either exposure or tayammum during travel she should do what is most logical to her and ask Allah for forgiveness, for in the end, only He is all-knowing. These protocols and procedures are set in place to provide Muslims with alternatives in times of need. We should use them justly and with good intentions, not out of idleness or convenience.

The Quran says: “Allah intends for you ease and does not intend for you hardship.” (Qur’an, 2:185)

Remember that excessive stringency of the rules does not necessarily equate to the level of piety.